Не влезают кнопки в экран мобильных устройств на сайте


На компьютере все нормально видно. Но на телефоне видны только три кнопки(и то не на всех устройствах). Если надо вот код: https://pastebin.com/yAWh3njd
P. S. не судите строго если вопрос тупой или код кривой, я только осваиваю разработку сайтов)

А еще меньше скрины есть? Код в вопросе должен быть. Так же стили, которые отвечают за это. Ну и желаемое поведение так же должно быть указано.

Добавьте в CSS следующее - nav { flex-wrap: wrap; }

Бургер функионал на чистом CSS


/* На будущее */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #FFFFFF;

  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

header img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 99px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

nav a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

nav a.active,
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
}

main {
  padding: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
}

footer a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
}

.card {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label[for="burger"] {
  display: none;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    margin-top: 72px;
    transition: 150ms;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    height: max(100%, fit-content);
    padding: 64px 0;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  label[for="burger"] {
    display: flex;
  }
  #burger:checked~nav {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <img src="/resources/logo.png" width="99" height="60" alt="NRT Corp logo">

  <label for="burger">Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="burger">

  <nav>
    <a href="/index.html">Главная</a>
    <a href="/staff.html">Команда</a>
    <a href="/news.html">Новости</a>
    <a href="/help.html">Помощь</a>
    <a href="/projects.html">Проекты</a>
    <a href="/misc.html">Другое</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="title">404</div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFiq6bSGb_povRUnrq2ONTKQc5Bd8Fjt3QRUNXzvKnkw&s">
    <p>Кажется, ты попал не туда. Попробуй снова.</p>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  &copy; 2024 NRT Corp. Все права защищены антивирусом Касперского. | <a href="privacy.html">Политика
  конфиденциальности</a>
</footer>



